# JMeter test without user action

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, testing, jmeter

I have a website that has a button which selects files, and then sends it to a server side. I want to use JMeter to test performace of application. Is there a way to test it without using recording and without any user actions? I want to have my files hardcoded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending files is done via [POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) or [PUT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/PUT) request so if you can figure out from the website page source code what is the proper format of the request then you should be able to replicate it using [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler with [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) or [HTTP Raw Request](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-http-raw-request-sampler-when-and-how-to-use-it) sampler

If you cannot or not willing to use JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) and cannot guess the proper request format yourself you can use your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) or 3rd-party proxy tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to capture the payload associated with the request and simulate it using JMeter test elements

Comment: When I use HTTP Request on my website I get an error, but when I do it on other website everything seems to be fine. Do you know what might be the problem?